# Running Multiple Angular Application In Sub Directory With Single Root Folder with NGINX

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have multiple angular apps that  have to be placed under single root folder.

For example i've host : example.com

So the apps will be under example.com/test1 and example.com/test2, etc

How do i load test1,test2,test3 etc dynamically read each assets?

The problems is assets are read on root folder and it's doesn't exist.

Here my config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
    index index.html;

    location /assets {
        return 301 http://example.com/$request_uri;
    }

    location /(.*)$ {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Goals :

assets folder should read on each test directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the root folder for your `/assets/...` requests based on HTTP `Referer` header:

```
map $http_referer $root_prefix {
    ~^http://example\.com(/[^/]+)/    $1;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /assets {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html/app$root_prefix;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've test config that you provide, but it's seem the URL cannot segment the application.
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test1'

Comment: That was not the scope of your question. Can you explain your folders structure? Where are these apps physically located? And you shouldn't mark the answer as accepted unless it is tested and works.

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry. I've done it by set build base_href